# Summing values for a month in R

Tags: r, date, dataframe, ggvis

please see data sample as follows:

```
3326    2015-03-03  Wm Eu Apple 2L       60
3327    2015-03-03 Tp Euro 2 Layer      420
3328    2015-03-03     Tpe 3-Layer       80
3329    2015-03-03        14/3 Bgs      145
3330    2015-03-04             T/P      196
3331    2015-03-04  Wm Eu Apple 2L    1,260
3332    2015-03-04 Tp Euro 2 Layer      360
3333    2015-03-04        14/3 Bgs    1,355
```

Currently graphing this data creates a really horrible graph because the amount of cartons change so rapidly by day. It would make more sense to sum the cartons by month so that each data point represents a sum for that month rather than an individual day. The current range of the data is 11/01/2008-04/01/2015.

This is the code that I am using to graph (which may or may not be relevant for this):

```
ggvis(myfile, ~Shipment.Date, ~ctns) %>%
layer_lines()
```

Shipment.Date is column 2 in the data set and ctns is the 4th column.

I don't know much about R and have given it a few trys with some code that I have found here but I don't think I have found a problem similar enough to match the code. My idea is to create a new table, sum Act. Ctns for the month and then save it as that new table and graph from there.

Thanks for any assistance! :)

Comment: Have a search on `aggregate` on the `[r]` tag to arrange your data

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30544258/summing-rows-by-month-in-r might help

Comment: I don't know how I didn't find that! I'll give it a shot at work on Monday but I think that is doable for my situation. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Do you need this:

```
 data.aggregated<-aggregate(list(new.value=data$value), 
                              by=list(date.time=cut(data$date.time, breaks="1 month")), 
                              FUN=function(x) sum(x))
```