# Summing rows by month over years in R

Tags: r, date, dplyr, time-series, lubridate

[Summing rows by month in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30544258/summing-rows-by-month-in-r)

So I used this post to sum up my data by month in R, but the problem is, my data goes over multiple years. The current solution will treat, say, Jan 2018 and Jan 2019 as the same month. Is there a way to have them separated by month using the aggregate() and month() functions? Or will I have to change my approach?

My data frame looks like this:

```
           Day           Sales
    1      2019-02-04    219.12        
    2      2019-02-04    60.84
    3      2019-02-05    200.27
    4      2020-02-11    157.17
    5      2020-02-12    12.14
```

And my function looks like this:

```
bymonth<-aggregate(sales~month(day,label=TRUE),data=total.orders.by.date,FUN=sum)
```

Thanks

---

Comment: Is this what you want: `total.orders.by.date %>% mutate(Month=month(Day,label = T),Year=year(Day)) %>% group_by(Year,Month) %>% summarise(Sales=sum(Sales,na.rm=T))`?

Comment: Yes, this is exactly what I'm looking for! Thank you.

Comment: I have added as possible solution. If you think the answer was helpful you could accept it by clicking the tick on the left side of the answer :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this:

```
library(tidyverse)
library(lubridate)
#Data
total.orders.by.date <- structure(list(Day = structure(c(17931, 17931, 17932, 18303, 
18304), class = "Date"), Sales = c(219.12, 60.84, 200.27, 157.17, 
12.14)), row.names = c("1", "2", "3", "4", "5"), class = "data.frame")

#Code
total.orders.by.date %>% mutate(Month=month(Day,label = T),Year=year(Day)) %>%
  group_by(Year,Month) %>% summarise(Sales=sum(Sales,na.rm=T))
```

Output:

```
# A tibble: 2 x 3
# Groups:   Year [2]
   Year Month Sales
  <dbl> <ord> <dbl>
1  2019 Feb    480.
2  2020 Feb    169.
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example using `lubridate` library

```
library(tidyverse)
library(lubridate)
result<-data.frame(Date=as.Date(c("18/12/2013", "12/12/2019", "15/8/2017", "09/08/2018"), format = "%d/%m/%Y"), Item = c(8002, 8004, 8001, 8002), result=c(21.45, 5.35, 35.99, 20.83)) 
result_2 <- result %>% 
  mutate(Month_only = month(Date)) %>% 
  group_by(Month_only) %>% 
  filter(between(Month_only, 1, 12)) %>% 
  summarise(total = sum(result, rm.na =TRUE))

#     Month_only total
#         <dbl> <dbl>
# 1          8  56.8
# 2         12  26.8
```